# Wifi not working on any Linux distro

Tags: networking, wifi, kernel-modules, firmware

I have a HP 255 G2 notebook PC.

I stuck with Linux Mint 17.1 after a hopping through a few distros. After I upgraded to LM 18, WiFi wasn't working anymore.

Being the noob that I am, I just tried installing other distros. Their live DVDs/USBs all had the WiFi working, but after installation (sometimes only after upgrading and updating) it wouldn't work anymore.

Now I have UberStudent 4.3 installed, which worked - until the first reboot.

`lspci` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini [Radeon HD 8330]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 0
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:02.5 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 3a)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 02)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 5
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

`lsmod` output:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
pci_stub               16384  1 
vboxpci                24576  0 
vboxnetadp             28672  0 
vboxnetflt             28672  0 
vboxdrv               466944  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
bnep                   20480  0 
rfcomm                 69632  0 
binfmt_misc            20480  1 
uvcvideo               90112  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         49152  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_core
videodev              172032  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
hp_wmi                 16384  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
amd_freq_sensitivity    16384  0 
kvm_amd                61440  0 
kvm                   507904  1 kvm_amd
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1 
arc4                   16384  2 
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1 
crc32_pclmul           16384  0 
snd_seq_midi           16384  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
ath9k                 143360  0 
snd_hda_intel          36864  5 
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
ath3k                  20480  0 
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
btusb                  45056  0 
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
aesni_intel           167936  0 
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
ath9k_hw              466944  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
btintel                16384  1 btusb
snd_hda_core           65536  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
ath                    32768  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
bluetooth             512000  9 bnep,ath3k,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
mac80211              729088  1 ath9k
dm_multipath           24576  0 
cryptd                 20480  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
scsi_dh                16384  1 dm_multipath
joydev                 20480  0 
input_leds             16384  0 
serio_raw              16384  0 
cfg80211              540672  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
edac_core              53248  0 
fam15h_power           16384  0 
edac_mce_amd           24576  0 
k10temp                16384  0 
snd_pcm               102400  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0 
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
i2c_piix4              24576  0 
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    81920  21 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
shpchp                 36864  0 
soundcore              16384  1 snd
hp_wireless            16384  0 
mac_hid                16384  0 
parport_pc             32768  0 
ppdev                  20480  0 
lp                     20480  0 
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
btrfs                 950272  0 
xor                    24576  1 btrfs
raid6_pq              102400  1 btrfs
dm_mirror              24576  0 
dm_region_hash         20480  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 20480  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
amdgpu                811008  0 
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0 
amdkfd                122880  1 
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfd
radeon               1507328  3 
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 amdgpu,radeon
ttm                    94208  2 amdgpu,radeon
drm_kms_helper        126976  2 amdgpu,radeon
psmouse               126976  0 
ahci                   36864  2 
drm                   360448  7 ttm,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,radeon
libahci                32768  1 ahci
r8169                  81920  0 
rtsx_pci               53248  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
mii                    16384  1 r8169
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi
video                  36864  0
```

`dmesg | grep -i ath` output:

```
[   17.198709] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[   17.501525] ath: phy0: WB335 1-ANT card detected
[   17.501533] ath: phy0: Set BT/WLAN RX diversity capability
[   17.508317] ath: phy0: Enable LNA combining
[   17.509425] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x43
[   17.509431] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6a
[   17.509434] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   17.509439] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   17.509441] ath: Regpair used: 0x6a
[   17.616700] ieee80211 phy0: Atheros AR9565 Rev:1 mem=0xffffc90002700000, irq=39
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What does `dmesg | grep -i ath` say?

Comment: And FYI: You have a `AR9565` WLAN hardware using the `ath9k` driver, so that's what you need to google for. In particular you should make sure that the distros you randomly installed have a kernel that's new enough for whatever bugfixes this driver may need for your hardware. Looking at the kernel version (`/proc/version`) helps.

Comment: @VIPaul Please post the data into your question with good formatting!